# use search, find and replace text from one work sheet to other sheet in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I am not an expert in Excel but I have been using the format.

I am trying to make a roster of my staff in Excel sheet using formulas.

The 1st sheet I have uses the row name TIME as a priority and fills other columns with staff names.

[image: 1st sheet]

Now in the 2nd sheet, I want to use a formula in each staff ROW and the column automatically fills with the TIME at each name.

[image: 2nd sheet]

Please help me if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: I will attempt to help answer tomorrow when I'm in front of a computer if someone hasn't gotten to it first.

Comment: If a name in the first sheet appears next to two different time (e.g Tam on Monday and John on Tuesday), which time do you want displayed in Sheet 2, the first?

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDEX / MATCH` combo. Something like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$3:$B$9,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!C$3:C$9,0)),"OFF DAY")
```

Syntax:

`=INDEX(rng,index_number)` — returns the value based on the index number

`=MATCH(lookup_value,rng)` — returns the relative position of the lookup value

`=INDEX(rng,MATCH(lookup_value,rng))` — we know all the arguments except for one — `index_number`. Since the output of `MATCH` function is the same as the index_number, we're going to substitute the index_number with `MATCH` function.

You can almost think of the `INDEX/MATCH` combo as:

`=INDEX/MATCH(rng,search_value)`

`=IFERROR(value_or_expression_to_evaluate,value_to_return_if_error)` — and finally, we're going to wrap our formula with this one, which will return a value if there is no match, which means, in your example, employee is on-leave, on a rest-day, or whatever. Can be `=IFNA`, too.

Now, to return all values with multiple matched lookup_value just like in your example, where "Tam" have two shifts on Monday, you may use a trailing number with employee names, i.e. "Tam1" and "Tam2" to indicate the number of shift in a given day. Or you may also use a combination of `COUNTIF` function (to count the number of shift of "Tam") and `CONCATENATE` to join the results together so that the output is gonna be: `630-1430 / 1230-2200`. There are many ways to do it depending on your requirement.

Hope this helps..